# printf linux issue - lsusb returned values returning one long string

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu

I have a list of USB details where the list doesn't contain 'Foundation' (to get rid of Linux Foundation lines). I assigned them in the following way:

```
usb_details2()
    {
    bus=$(lsusb |grep -v Foundation | awk {'print $2'})
    device=$(lsusb |grep -v Foundation | awk {'print $4'})
    id=$(lsusb |grep -v Foundation | awk {'print $6'})
    name1=$(lsusb |grep -v Foundation | awk {'print $7'})
    name2=$(lsusb |grep -v Foundation | awk {'print $8'})
    name3=$(lsusb |grep -v Foundation | awk {'print $9'})
    name4=$(lsusb |grep -v Foundation | awk {'print $10'})
    name5=$(lsusb |grep -v Foundation | awk {'print $11'})
    name6=$(lsusb |grep -v Foundation | awk {'print $12'})
    name7=$(lsusb |grep -v Foundation | awk {'print $13'})
    name8=$(lsusb |grep -v Foundation | awk {'print $14'})
    name9=$(lsusb |grep -v Foundation | awk {'print $15'})

    printf "Bus: %s\tDevice: %s\tID: %s\t Device Name: %s %s %s" "$bus" "$device" "$id" "$name1" "$name2" "$name3" ...etc
}

echo $(usb_details2)
```

This just returns a mess:

```
Bus: 002 002 003 003 Device: 003: 007: 003: 002: ID: 058f:6366 148f:5370 045e:0745 093a:2510 Device Name: Alcor Ralink Microsoft Pixart Micro Technology, Corp. Imaging, Corp. Corp. Nano Inc.
```

This is what 'lsusb |grep -v Foundation' returns:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
```

Is there a way I can output it like this:

```
Bus   Device   ID           Device Name
002   003:     058f:6366    Alcor etc etc...
002   007:     148f:5370    ...
003   003:     ...          ... 
003   002:     ...          ...
```

There must be an easier way!
Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $(usb_details2)
```

That will combine all the output of `usb_details2` into one line, according to the shell's rules for [field splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05) using the default value for `IFS`. To preserve embedded newlines, use quotes:

```
echo "$(usb_details2)"
```

(Trailing newlines will still be removed, because of [command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03) rules.)

Even simpler: you don't have to use command substitution at all when you're just going to echo or printf the command's exact output.

```
usb_details2
```

It looks like you want to print columns 2, 4, 6, and the 7th through the last. Here's how to do it with a single pipeline and awk.

```
usb_details2() {
  lsusb | grep -v Foundation | awk '
    BEGIN {
      printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t\t%s\n", "Bus", "Device", "ID", "Device Name"
    }
    {
      printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t", $2, $4, $6
      for(i=7; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s ", $i
      printf "\n"
    }'
}

usb_details2
```

Comment: No need for `grep -v | awk` Use `$0 !~ /Foundation/ { ... }`

Comment: Cheers for the reply. I guessed it would need a for loop but had no idea you could do it like that! Thanks again.